# Is there a more efficient (i.e. faster) way to compute correlated random walks?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Is there any way to vectorize or otherwise speed this up?  I'm already jitting it using numba, but it is still a major bottleneck. Using numba to jit my functions on 1-d numpy arrays leads to code that is orders of magnitude faster, but there is essentially a negligible improvement when using numba on the 2-d arrays below.  decomposition is a numpy matrix representing the cholesky decomposition of the correlation matrix, and x and n are constants, and nrand is numpy.random

```
@jit
def generate_random_correlated_walks(decomposition, x, n):

    uncorrelated_walks = np.empty((2*x, n))

    for i in range(x):
        # Generate the random uncorrelated walks
        wv = nrand.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=n)
        ws = nrand.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=n)
        uncorrelated_walks[2*i] = wv
        uncorrelated_walks[(2*i) + 1] = ws

    # Create a matrix out of these walks
    uncorrelated_walks = np.matrix(uncorrelated_walks)

    m, n = uncorrelated_walks.shape
    correlated_walks = np.empty((m, n))

    # Go through column and correlate the walk values
    for i in range(n):
        correlated_timestep = np.transpose(uncorrelated_walks[:, i]) * decomposition
        correlated_walks[:, i] = correlated_timestep

    return correlated_walks
```

EDIT: I have made the suggested changes, and now my code is as below, but unfortunately still is a major bottleneck.  Any ideas?

```
@jit
def generate_random_correlated_walks(self, decomposition, x, n):

    rows = 2*x

    uncorrelated_walks = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(rows, n))

    correlated_walks = np.empty((rows, n))

    for i in range(n):
        correlated_timestep = np.dot(np.transpose(uncorrelated_walks[:, i]), decomposition)
        correlated_walks[:, i] = correlated_timestep

    return correlated_walks
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html
?

Comment: do you know if that uses cholesky to correlate the walks?

Comment: For one thing, you don't need that `for` loop at all. You just need a single call to `normal`, and please show your non-conventional imports (i.e., anything besides `np`, `plt`, `pd`, etc.)

Comment: Cholesky? [Probably not](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bb5d666e84e2eb294543a67c6143d7e9124d1c73/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L4512).

Comment: Also, use `np.array` instead of `np.matrix`

Comment: good call on array vs matrix, I can just use np.dot rather than the matrix mult operator

Comment: Also, just to clarify, `decomposition` is `2x * 2x` in size, right?

Comment: yep, that's correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you can improve is to remove your `for` loop. There is no advantage to calling [`np.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) a bunch of times with the same input parameters if you believe that it really generates random numbers.

Instead of using [`np.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), use [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). This will make your life easier when you consider that the previous item can be used to shorten the entire first portion of your function into one step.

You can of course completely remove the final loop with a simple matrix multiplication: `uncorrelated_walks.T @ decomposition` will give you the transpose of your current `correlated_walks`. You can avoid one of the [transposes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) by changing the order of the arguments.

You end up with something like:

```
def generate_random_correlated_walks(decomposition, x, n):
    uncorrelated_walks = nrand.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(2*x, n))
    correlated_walks = np.dot(decomposition.T, uncorrelated_walks)
    return correlated_walks
```

Not sure how much this will help you, but removing the Python-level loops should be some kind of boost since it will reduce the overhead of multiple numpy calls.

You could sacrifice legibility to turn the whole thing into a one-liner:

```
def generate_random_correlated_walks(decomposition, x, n):
    return np.dot(decomposition.T, nrand.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(2*x, n)))
```